# Process Builder causes Apex Class Test Failure - Stops Migration

Tags: process-builder, failing-tests

My searching for this only displayed a solution which wasn't relevant: [Process Builder and Test Classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76950/process-builder-and-test-classes)

**Use Case:**

1. We have a process that creates a chatter post on user record insert OR profile edit.
2. There is an apex test class that inserts a user (testuser) to run tests for 
   totally separate reasons.

**The problem:**

We ran into migration errors (changeset didn't validate) because the process wasn't able to effectively run.  The error we received from the process was "failed to create record (FeedItem), source record (User) was deleted."

After some investigation, we found that the apex class was creating a user, "testuser" and the process was then running and aiming to create a chatter post, however user was already deleted (due to being an apex test), and the FeedItem couldn't be loaded.

- We tried modifying the process to exclude any users named "testuser," which didn't work because the user record was already deleted (in retrospect, duh).
- Understood that we can disable the process, migrate, re-enable process, as well as deploying via metadata API.  However, we're looking for a fix instead of a bandaid.

Anyone come across this/have any solutions for the specific use case?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you run this test in your Sandbox do you get this issue, or is it only happening on deployment?

Comment: Adrian - Edited to add the wrong answer above.

Comment: Doug - this errors on tests and deployment within a sandbox - haven't tried in prod.

Comment: sounds like the Process is working with hard-coded users;

Comment: @crop1645 - do you have a link to any documentation?  Are you saying issue is avoided with a hard-coded user, or that the process I documented above has hard coded the user?  As a test class automatically generates and deletes (my assumption) a user before the process runs (order of execution), I wasn't aware of a way to persist any of the data for the process to run off of.

Comment: i was hypothesizing that your process is using a hard-coded user - which would not be good. A hypothesis only as you haven't included specifics of your process in the OP

Comment: @crop1645 - gotcha.  Nope, the process fires on user insert/edit then creates a feedItem attached to the user record that fired the process.  Doesn't have any id's or anything.  The test class simply creates a "test user" named something like Test0 User0.

Comment: Hi, You can add the condition in process builder for null check for user before inserting the feed related to the same.

Comment: Hi @AjayDubedi - Indeed I can.  The problem here is that the user literally exists (which kicks off the process) then is deleted (as it's a test class).  So the error comes in this sequence: Test class creates user, process triggers, test class deletes user, error.  (I think)